# Providing default value for unmapped column in SQL Compare

Tags: sqlcompare

Is it possible to provide a default value or a query to provide a value to an unmapped column in the target table using Redgate SQL Data Compare?

To explain the scenario I have a configuration database that holds settings data for several database instances. The data is all in the same shape, but the config database has an additional InstanceID field in most tables. This allows me to filter my compare to only compare against the InstanceID relating to the source Instance database. However if I generate Insert scripts they fail because the Target Instance ID fields are non nullable. I want to provide a default value that is then used in the Insert Scripts. Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Data Compare doesn't have an easy way of doing this I'm afraid.

There is one way to do it - you could create a view that selects everything from the source table along with a computed column, which just provides the "default value" that you want to insert. Then you can map the view to the table in the target database and compare them, deploying from the result.

I hope this helps.